# ActiveMQ selector expression with xpath and namespace

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces, activemq-classic

I need to create jms message filter selectors using xpath with namespace and prefix.

For below xml message/payload this xpath expression `XPATH &#39;//test/one/text()=''oneTest''&#39;` is working fine to me.

```
<test>
   <one>oneTest</one>
   <two>twoTest</two>
</test>
```

But I am unable write an xpath expression if my xml message has namespace and prefix like below.

```
<es:EnterpriseMessage
xmlns:es="http://schemas.umusic.com/enterprise/services/2014/05">
<es:EnterpriseHeader>
    <es:MessageId>123</es:MessageId>
</es:EnterpriseHeader>
```

I need to write a jms filter selector xpath expression with namespace like if MessageId element has '123' then only jms consumer should process the message.

Can some one please let me know how can we write AcitveMQ jms selector expression using xpath with namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use local-name()='elementName' to select the element whatever its namespace.
for example : `&#39;//*[local-name()=''test'']/*[local-name()=''one'']/text()=''oneTest''&#39;`

I hope this could help!